# Reading Properties of an Object with Expression Trees

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

I want to create a Lambda Expression for every Property of an Object that reads the value dynamically.

What I have so far:

```
var properties = typeof (TType).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead);

foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
{
    var getterMethodInfo = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();

    var entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TType));

    var getterCall = Expression.Call(entity, getterMethodInfo);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(getterCall, entity);
    var expression = (Expression<Func<TType, "TypeOfProperty">>) lambda;
    var functionThatGetsValue = expression.Compile();
}
```

The code Works well when i call `functionThatGetsValue` as long as "TypeOfProperty" is hardcoded. I know that I can't pass the "TypeOfPoperty" dynamically. What can I do to achive my goal?

Comment: What is your goal? You say you want to create a lambda expression; do you only need the compiled delegate (`functionThatGetsValue`), or do you need the intermediate expression tree too (`expression`)?

Comment: @LukeH, just the compiled delegate. thanks. (My goal is to iterate through a list of objects, and read all the values from the properties. To gain a bit of performance I want to do it this way instead of using reflection)

Comment: When I tried to achieve similar result I ended with returning Func<Type, Object> and casting return value to specific property type on caller`s side.

Comment: I agree with Nechytailo that you'll probably need to create your delegate as a `Func<TType,object>`, invoke it, and then cast the result to its specific type (if necessary).

Comment: I would be fine with that, but the problem is that from "getterMethodInfo" it takes the actualy type and when I try to cast the lambda to Func<TType,object> it can't be casted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you're happy with a `Func<TType, object>` delegate (as per the comments above), you can use [`Expression.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335409.aspx) to achieve that:

```
var properties = typeof(TType).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead);

foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
{
    MethodInfo getterMethodInfo = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();
    ParameterExpression entity = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TType));
    MethodCallExpression getterCall = Expression.Call(entity, getterMethodInfo);

    UnaryExpression castToObject = Expression.Convert(getterCall, typeof(object));
    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(castToObject, entity);

    var functionThatGetsValue = (Func<TType, object>)lambda.Compile();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

After hours of googling found the answer [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2009/04/10/using-expression-trees-to-get-property-getter-and-setters.aspx). I've added the snippets from the blog post as it might help others having the same troubles:

```
public static class PropertyInfoExtensions
{
    public static Func<T, object> GetValueGetter<T>(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != propertyInfo.DeclaringType)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, "i");
        var property = Expression.Property(instance, propertyInfo);
        var convert = Expression.TypeAs(property, typeof(object));
        return (Func<T, object>)Expression.Lambda(convert, instance).Compile();
    }

    public static Action<T, object> GetValueSetter<T>(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != propertyInfo.DeclaringType)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, "i");
        var argument = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "a");
        var setterCall = Expression.Call(
            instance,
            propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(),
            Expression.Convert(argument, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
        return (Action<T, object>)Expression.Lambda(setterCall, instance, argument).Compile();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified gsharp's post above to actually set the value directly and make it a bit easier to use. It's not ideal as there is the introduction of the DynamicCast function which requires you to know your type up front. My goal was to try to keep us strongly typed and not return object and avoid dynamic keyword. Also, keep "magic" to a minimum.

```
  public static T DynamicCast<T>(this object value)
    {
        return (T) value;
    }
    public static object GetPropertyValue<T>(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo, T objectInstance)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != propertyInfo.DeclaringType)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, "i");
        var property = Expression.Property(instance, propertyInfo);
        var convert = Expression.TypeAs(property, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        var lambda =  Expression.Lambda(convert, instance).Compile();
        var result = lambda.DynamicInvoke(objectInstance);


        return result;
    }

    public static void SetPropertyValue<T, TP>(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo, T objectInstance, TP value)
        where T : class
        where TP : class
    {
        if (typeof(T) != propertyInfo.DeclaringType)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType, "i");
        var argument = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.PropertyType, "a");
        var setterCall = Expression.Call(
            instance,
            propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(),
            Expression.Convert(argument, propertyInfo.PropertyType));

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(setterCall, instance, argument).Compile();
        lambda.DynamicInvoke(objectInstance, value);
    }
```

Examples:

```
    public void Get_Value_Of_Property()
    {
        var testObject = new ReflectedType
        {
            AReferenceType_No_Attributes = new object(),
            Int32WithRange1_10 = 5,
            String_Requires = "Test String"
        };

        var result = testObject.GetType().GetProperty("String_Requires").GetPropertyValue(testObject).DynamicCast<string>();

        result.Should().Be(testObject.String_Requires);
    }

    public void Set_Value_Of_Property()
    {
        var testObject = new ReflectedType
        {
            AReferenceType_No_Attributes = new object(),
            Int32WithRange1_10 = 5,
            String_Requires = "Test String"
        };

        testObject.GetType().GetProperty("String_Requires").SetPropertyValue(testObject, "MAGIC");

        testObject.String_Requires.Should().Be("MAGIC");
    }
```

You *could* write a helper method which uses MakeGenericMethod  or an expression tree to make a lambda do the typed call to call DynamicCast based on the PropertyInfo object and avoid having to know it up front. But that is less elegant.