# How to read the values of a property in expression tree?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'd like to read the value of some of the properties in the expression tree some I can proceed to some calculations.

```
var products = db.Products
    .Where(GetPredicate())
    .ToList();

private Expression<Func<Product, bool>>  GetPredicate()
{
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");
    Expression exp0 = Expression.Property(pe, "Price");

   //I'd like to know the value of the 'Price'
   // so I can do some calculation, then check whether 
   //this particular product meet the criteria...

   Expression body = Expression.Constant(Result);  //result is a boolean
   var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(body, new ParameterExpression[] { pe });
        return expr;

}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the Expression.Convert ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Properties of an Object with Expression Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436323/reading-properties-of-an-object-with-expression-trees)

Comment: When you are creating Expression tree in `GetPredicate` you don't have a value of `Price` (because you don't have `Product` object). So you cannot retrive real value before you pass it to the compiled expression tree. But you can add to expression tree some kind of comparisons and constraints as you want. Something looks like this: `Expression.Add(exp0, Expression.Constant(156));` then you can check returned value and etc. But you don't not know value yet, you only know that your input value will be compared and etc. Did I miss something or didn't understand your question?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria, so `exp0` should be considered as variable to be used in the formulas? I tried something like `Math.Sqrt(exp0);` and got an error: `Cannot convert 'System.Linq.Expression.Expression' to 'double'`.

Comment: `exp0` should be `Expression` if you want to use it at some formula that represents as `Expression`. Let me show a simple example: you have `(value + 4) * 3 + 2`. It's a simple formula that contains one input parameter. You can represent it as Expression Tree: `var expVal = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));            Expression.Add(Expression.Multiply(Expression.Add(expVal, Expression.Constant(4)), Expression.Constant(3)), Expression.Constant(2));`. So your example `Math.Sqrt(value)` also can be represented as Expression Tree.

Comment: Could you give a bit of context please? You have a db with products and want to do some math in some conditions? Dont go lowlevel. Db.Products.Where(p=> (p.Price>mythreshold? p.Price-7 : p.Price +2) % 3 == 1).ToList(). Also remember that you are delegating the calculation to Sql, so can only use sg that the db understands

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be using a database query provider (LINQ2SQL, EF, etc.)

Before you try to use expressions to solve your problem you need to make sure the expression is understood by the query provider. In your case many of the `Math` methods can be converted to T-SQL valid statements. Also, if you are using Entity Framework you might want to leverage the `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions` class to create an expression and execute your logic on the SQL Server side against native T-SQL functions.

**Now**, something to understand on expression trees, is that values cannot be obtained from constructing expressions unless this is a `LambdaExpression`, once compiled you invoke it, in your case you can obtain the `bool` value.

If you need to work with the price value, you need to create more expressions representing the call to the other logic, in your example the expressions calling the static `Sqrt` method of the `Math` class.

```
private Expression<Func<Product, bool>> GetPredicate()
{
   var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "p");
   var price = Expression.Property(pe, "Price");
   var priceDouble = Expression.Convert(price, typeof(double));
   var sqrtMethod = typeof(Math).GetMethod("Sqrt");
   var sqrtCall = Expression.Call(sqrtMethod, priceDouble);
   var constant = Expression.Constant(4d);
   var gtThan = Expression.GreaterThan(sqrtCall, constant);

   var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>(gtThan, pe);
   return lambda;
}
```

As you can see all the logic is an expression and the provider can consume the whole expression and convert it to syntax that can be understood by the target process. The prior expression generates **`p => Math.Sqrt((double)p.Price) > 4d`**