# Dynamically copy certain properties between two class instances

Tags: c#, copy, expression-trees, getter-setter

I am attempting to write a piece of code that can **take two instances of the same object, and copy some properties from the first one to the second one, dynamically**. A little twist is that I only have access to the objects, through an interface they both inherit.

I have created a `Copyable` attribute that will be used to mark what properties can be copied.

I then managed to successfully do this using the `PropertyInfo.GetMethod` and `PropertyInfo.SetMethod`, however the resulting code is **too slow**. When comparing to **statically assigning properties at compile time** - this approach is **~20 times slower**.

Here is my initial implementation using pure reflection.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp58
{
    interface IInterface
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    class CopyableAttribute : Attribute { }

    class Child : IInterface
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Copyable]
        public int CopyableProp { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var source = new Child() {Id = 1, CopyableProp = 42};
            var target = new Child() {Id = 2, CopyableProp = 0};

            CopyProps(source, target);
        }

        static void CopyProps(IInterface source, IInterface target)
        {
            var props = target.GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(CopyableAttribute), false))
                .ToArray();

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                var value = prop.GetMethod.Invoke(source, new object[] { });
                prop.SetMethod.Invoke(target, new [] {value});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This works, but its slow**, so I decided to attempt and create an expression tree that will build a lambda that can call the getters and setters, however I can't seem to make it work.

I tried following [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436323/reading-properties-of-an-object-with-expression-trees), however, that implementation relies on the fact that I know what's the type of my object that I'm taking the properties from.

However, in my case the properties are defined as part of child classes, and I have no access to them in my `IInterface`.

Hence, I'm asking here. **Is there a (fast) way for me to copy the value of specific properties, between instances of two objects, by referring to them only through their common interface**.

Comment: I thought it was clear from the code. I have two instances of `IInterface` that are both of type `Child`. I want to take all properties with `Copyable` attribute from the `source` instance and copy their values over to the `target` instance.

And I want to do it as fast as possible

Comment: The first instance is an input that comes after deserializing an API request. I need to take certain properties and copy them over to another instance, which contains a sort of "default" values for each property. The second instance takes the needed properties from the original and is then passed to other business layers for usage. I cannot reuse the same instance, as this is later passed to other components that I have no control over and its properties' references might be modified. I also cannot use concrete types due to other system specifics, that are not relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate `Action<IInterface, IInterface>` by Expression API. Try this code:

```
private static Expression<Action<IInterface, IInterface>> CreateCopyMethod(Type type)
{
    var props = type
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(CopyableAttribute), false))
        .ToArray();


    var s = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IInterface), "s");
    var t = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IInterface), "t");

    var source = Expression.Variable(type, "source");
    var castToSource = Expression.Assign(source, Expression.Convert(s, type));

    var target = Expression.Variable(type, "target");
    var castToTarget = Expression.Assign(target, Expression.Convert(t, type));

    var instructions = new List<Expression>
    {
        castToSource, castToTarget
    };
    foreach (var property in props)
    {
        var left = Expression.Property(target, property);
        var right = Expression.Property(source, property);
        var assign = Expression.Assign(left, right);

        instructions.Add(assign);
    }

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<IInterface, IInterface>>(
        Expression.Block(
            new[] {source, target}, instructions),
        s, t);
    return lambda;
}
```

Usage

```
IInterface src = new Child
{
    CopyableProp = 42
};
IInterface dst = new Child();

var copy = CreateCopyMethod(src.GetType()).Compile();
copy(src, dst);

Console.WriteLine(((Child)dst).CopyableProp); // 42
```

To improve performance consider usage `Dictionary<Type, Action<IInterface, IInterface>>` to cache implementation of already generated methods

Comment: Works like a charm. This exactly what I needed. After caching the Action lambdas in a dictionary - the performance is just a couple times slower (2-3) than static assignment. Which, while not ideal, is still 10 times faster than normal reflection. And I think I can optimize it event futher. Thanks a lot!